# Casting vs Parsing vs Serialization in Java: What are the differences?

Tags: java, parsing, serialization, casting

These 3 terms deal with the conversion from one form to another, which seems similar and confusing. In general, which unique features make them distinct? Under what situation(s) what should each be used?

Comment: Casting only changes the compiler's view, the actual data is not changed. Parsing is the process of analyzing some string of symbols. Serialising is the process of transforming an object into a format that can be stored.

Comment: Casting is a mechanism to specify compile time type conversion. Parsing is a mechanism to convert text into state at runtime. Serialization (and deserialization) about writing (or reading) object state to/from a compact writable binary representation.

Comment: What is the context you are having here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are similar in that all 3 deal in converting data from one representation to another one (almost, casting reference types is a bit special).

### 1. Casting

In Java casting does two different things, depending on whether you're casting references or primitive values:

- casting a reference simply changes the *type of the reference*, it does **not** change anything about the Object. For example:

  ```
    Object a = "a string constant";
    String b = (String) a;
  ```

  After running this code both `a` and `b` will point to the exact same object (of type `String` representing the value `"a string constant"`). The difference is just that `a` is a `Object` type reference and `b` is a `String` type reference. This limits what you can call (so `a.length()` won't work, but `b.length()` will work).

  Casting a reference type will only succeed when the object being referenced *is actually of a compatible type*. So if `o` was initialized as `new Object()` in the code block above, then the cast on the second line would fail with a `ClassCastException`.
- casting a primitive type *does* potentially change the value in question, depending on the range and resolution of the target type:

  ```
    int i = 1000;
    char c = (char) i;
    byte b = (byte) i;
  ```

  Here the `int` value `1000` is cast both to `char` and to `byte`. The first cast just leaves `c` equal to `1000`. But `byte` can't hold the value `1000`, so it will be truncated to `-24`.

## 2. Parsing

[Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) is about converting textual data to a more specific representation. The simplest example of parsing is something like this:

```
String s = "1000";
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

`s` holds the *textual representation* of the number 1000, i.e. the Unicode characters U+0031 U+0030 U+0030 U+0030. `Integer.parseInt` takes that text representation and converts it into an `int` type.

However, parsing can describe a wide variety of processes ranging from simple ones as above, slightly more complex ones like parsing a decimal number or date up to arbitrarily complex object trees.

As an example: The Java compiler will *parse* the Java source code and convert it into an internal representation that will then be further processed.

According to some definitions parsing can also apply to non-text inputs, as long as the input is some set of symbols (which could just be bytes), but that interpretation is rather rare.

## 3. Serialization

[Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is the process of turning data or program state into something that can easily be stored or transferred. Usually that means into a byte stream (or more directly, a `byte[]`).

Similarly to parsing, serialization can apply to very simple one-value transformations down to serializing whole object trees and writing them to files.

In Java Serialization usually refers to the mechanism surrounding [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), but the term is also used to describe the general concept (i.e. other formats can also be described as "serialization").